# How to control a script is not already running?

Tags: shell, ps

I have a shell script executed by cron and I want to control that it's not already running.
This is my control test:

```
set -A processes
ps -elf | grep -v grep | grep -E "/bin/ksh.+scriptName" | while read line ;do processes[${#processes[@]}]="$line";done
if [ ${#processes[@]} -gt 1 ]; then
    for i in {0..$((${#processes[@]}-1))}; do echo "${processes[$i]}"; done
    exit 1
fi
```

The problem is that this control returns sometimes 2 processes (of itself):

> F S UID        PID  PPID  C PRI  NI ADDR SZ WCHAN  STIME TTY         TIME CMD
>
> 0 S user     12486 12485  0  85   0 -  2469 -      15:30 ?       00:00:00 /bin/ksh /path/scriptName ARG1
>
> 1 D user     12503 12486  0  85   0 -  2469 get_wr 15:30 ?       00:00:00 /bin/ksh
>   /path/scriptName ARG1

I do not understand why it happens sometimes...How to resolve this problem?
How to control a script is not already running (without "flag"/semaphore file)?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your script is broken in quite a number of areas.. (1) nothing fills the `processes` array. (`line` is filled by `read`). (2) you cannot use variable arguments with brace expansion in a for loop (not without bastardizing it). E.g. `{0..$((${#processes[@]}-1))}` does not work. `i` becomes `{0..somenum}` not `0 1 2 3 ... somenum`. You will have better luck with the command `pidof` to locate the process you want to control --or-- have your cron script write its PID out (`$$`) to a temp file and launch a subshell to read the pid and do what you need. Just a few thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

1. Allow the job to start, but have scriptName script check if it is
   already running and kill itself.
2. Switch to a more sophisticated
   job scheduler such as http://nerds.airbnb.com/introducing-chronos/

Answer (score 0):

Using pipes can spawn subprocesses, which show up in the process table.  Limit the "ps" output and it becomes easier to parse:

```
ps -eo pid,ppid,args | grep -vw $$ | grep -qE "[0-9]+ /bin/ksh $0" && echo "ALREADY RUNNING"
```

This removes anything from the list that has the current PID ($$) as its PID or Parent PID, and then matches the scriptname as a pattern.  You really don't even need the "[0-9]+" in the pattern, since the first grep excludes all of your child processes (otherwise the "grep" itself would match).